# Display date or time on the values axis (y-axis) of a chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

I have a process that produces widgets at a variable rate.  The number of widgets produced every 5 minutes is reported to a log.  Knowing how many widgets must be produced in total, I can use the number of widgets produced in any timeframe to compute the estimated time of completion (ETC) of the process.  But how can I make Excel show the ETC on the y-axis?

For example, this data shows sample time; count of widgets since the process started; (computed) average number of widgets produced per minute from record 1 to the current record; and the (computed) ETC based on the average, the known total number of widgets (127830) to be produced, and the current time.

```
+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+
|    Time     | Count | Average |     ETC     |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 11:39:20 AM |   256 |         |             |
| 11:44:20 AM | 13083 |    2617 | 12:27:20 PM |
| 11:49:20 AM | 27979 |    2798 | 12:24:20 PM |
| 11:54:20 AM | 28196 |    1880 | 12:47:20 PM |
| 11:59:20 AM | 28201 |    1410 | 1:09:20 PM  |
| 12:04:20 PM | 28791 |    1152 | 1:29:20 PM  |
| 12:09:20 PM | 28936 |     965 | 1:51:20 PM  |
| 12:14:20 PM | 52237 |    1492 | 1:04:20 PM  |
| 12:19:20 PM | 56599 |    1415 | 1:09:20 PM  |
| 12:24:20 PM | 59948 |    1332 | 1:14:20 PM  |
| 12:29:20 PM | 66523 |    1330 | 1:15:20 PM  |
| 12:34:20 PM | 69557 |    1265 | 1:20:20 PM  |
| 12:39:20 PM | 74458 |    1241 | 1:22:20 PM  |
| 12:44:20 PM | 80642 |    1241 | 1:22:20 PM  |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

When I chart this in Excel, I get the ETC (time) values as fractions of a day.
[image: Excel chart showing time as a fraction of a day]

I see the y-axis has a property named "Display units" that allows me to show the values as thousands or millions, but not date or time.  Am I missing something, or is this just a limitation of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right-click on the labels and choose "Format Axis from the drop down menu

[image]

2. Under "Number", choose the number format you  want (Time)

[image]

This should give you the desired result:

[image]